# Is there a way to disable a specific notation in Coq?

Tags: coq, notation

I'd like, in Coqide, to have the proof state not use a certain notation (but still use all others).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand in the documentation, it is not possible. You might be able to play with opening/closing scopes but I'm not sure it will work, since it is stated explicitly that notations will be used for printing whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Some tricks that might be sufficient are described here: [How to disable my custom notation in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294602/how-to-disable-my-custom-notation-in-coq)

I wanted to add pointer to that answer because this question comes up first on Google.

Comment: Good try, but those tricks aren't sufficient to do specifically what the question asks.