# unfold notation in ltac

Tags: coq, ltac

I noticed notations can be treated differently. For example `<` is just notation for a regular definition and `unfold "<"` does work as in the following example:

```
Theorem a : 4 < 5.
Proof.
    unfold "<".
```

However, `<=` is notation associated with the type `le` and for some reason `unfold "<="` doesn't work, as in the following example:

```
Theorem a : 4 <= 5
Proof.
   unfold "<=".
```

which fails with `Unable to interpret "<=" as a reference`.

Can I convert `4 <= 5` into `le 4 5` with some ltac command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Anton's answer: If you already know how the notation is defined and only want to make it visible in the goal, you could do something like

```
Definition make_visible {X} (f : X) := f.

Notation "` f" := (make_visible f) (at level 5, format "` f").

Tactic Notation "unfold" "notation" constr(f) :=
  change f with (`f).
Tactic Notation "fold" "notation" constr(f) :=
  unfold make_visible.

Theorem a : 4 <= 5.
Proof.
  unfold notation le.
  fold notation le.
```

(Edit: My first solution was `Definition make_visible {X} (f : X) := (fun _ => f) tt.`, but, as Anton pointed out, this is easier.)

Comment: Nice! I've noticed that a simple wrapper also works: `Definition make_visible {X} (f : X) := f.` Is there a case when it fails?

Comment: Ah, no, I think that's even better. When playing around I first didn't introduce a definition and defined the notation directly, thus the strange detour. I'll change the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `<` is interpreted as `lt` which is a *definition* ([here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Peano.html#lt)):

```
Definition lt (n m:nat) := S n <= m.
```

You can achieve the same effect with `unfold lt`.

In the same manner `<=` means `le`, but you cannot unfold `le`, because it is a type constructor. The manual says that you can unfold only a defined transparent constant or local definition.

The upshot here is that you don't unfold notations, you unfold the definitions those notations refer to.

Comment: Makes sense, unfold works only on definitions. However, if I wanted `a <= b` to be displayed as `le a b` in the proof view, is there a tactic or something I can execute in the middle of the proof to do it?

Comment: There is `Unset Printing Notations.` command, but it unfolds them *all*. There is no way to do it selectively as of now. Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30248144/2747511). And here are related issues: [#5591](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/5591) and [#703](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/703).